# SELECT-CASE-IN-SELECT error: [SQL0115] Comparison operator IN not valid. In query db2

Tags: sql, select, db2, case

i have a problem in a db2 query

I tried run this query

```
SELECT t.* , 
  CASE WHEN column in (SELECT data FROM otherTable WHERE conditions...)
   then 5
   else 0
  end as 'My new data'
FROM table t 
WHERE conditions....
```

But get error

```
 [Error Code: -115, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0115] Comparison operator IN not valid.
```

When i change the sub-query to where statement like this

```
SELECT t.*      
FROM table t 
WHERE column in (SELECT data FROM otherTable WHERE conditions...)
```

Works fine

Why not work in the case statement? It is a limitation of db2?

And could make an equivalent behavior?

Comment: Care to mention your DB2 platform and version?

Comment: @mustaccio `DB2 UDB for AS/400` version `07.01.0000 V7R1m0`

Comment: [As the error message says](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzala/rzalaml.htm%23messages__SQL0115?lang=en), the IBM i 7.1 SQL does not allow subselects in the CASE expression. You'll have to rewrite your query, as @Hogan suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to left join to the table and check if it is not null.

In most cases this will be the fastest way because SQL servers are optimized to perform joins very quickly (but will depend on a number of factors including data model, indexes, data size, etc).

Like this:

```
SELECT t.* , 
  CASE WHEN othertable.data is not null
   then 5
   else 0
  end as 'My new data'
FROM table t 
left join otherTable ON otherTable.column = data
WHERE conditions....
```

Comment: @mustaccio - reworded, my statement was valid for this version of DB2 but not in the general case.  Since my answer is useful for the general case I reworded to make you happy.

Answer (score 1):

Try with using `exists` condition as below (put the column value in the where clause of subquery) :

```
SELECT t.* , 
  CASE WHEN exists (SELECT data FROM otherTable WHERE conditions... and column=val)
   then 5
   else 0
  end as 'My new data'
FROM table t 
WHERE conditions....
```

Comment: this could be slow if it has to execute the select for every row of table.

Comment: yes, of course, I just wanted to show another replacement of `case column in (select ... from)` only on base of given query in question, I didn't want to change his/her query. I only corrected the case statement. and am sure this tip is useful.

Comment: as an aside, `EXISTS` won't work with this version of SQL cf http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstcasestmt.htm?lang=en

Comment: Sorry, but you can test a `CASE WHEN exists... ` in a real DB2 system. –

Comment: @Hogan before this answer and before my answer to your comments I didn't see the comments under question because the comments were came 6 hours after mine and your answer and I see them just now. anyway, good luck.