# Case in Select statement returns an error

Tags: sql, select, db2, case

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('C','~') AS "1", FFIITMN,
    CASE WHEN FFIITMN IN (SELECT FGDITMN FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FGDPRPIP WHERE FGDCMPN = '  1' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS "16"
FROM 
    S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP --Item master file
    JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFJITMBP ON FFJITMN = FFIITMN AND FFJCMPN = FFICMPN --Item balance file
    JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFBCLSAP ON FFBCLSN = FFJCLSN AND FFBCMPN = FFICMPN --Item class file

WHERE 
    FFICMPN = '  1' 
AND
    FFIITMN = '    365725'
```

Returns the error:

> Comparison operator IN not valid.. SQLCODE=-115, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56

Is it possible to use a case statement in select to check to see if the item number is in another table?

Comment: Please format and present your SQL query in a readable fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got mis-matched brackets - the closing bracket should be at the end of the inner `SELECT` query, not at the end of the `CASE` block:

```
CASE WHEN FFIITMN IN (SELECT FGDITMN FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FGDPRPIP WHERE FGDCMPN = '  1') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS "16"
```

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I have been trying different things, when I format it that way I get the error that I posted. The inner select statement works fine but I still get an error when running the query.

Comment: @DanB. What error? If it's the error from your question, then what type are the `FFITMN` / `FGDITMN` columns? And which specific DBMS are you using?

Comment: Richard, FFIITMN and FGDITMN are both A,10, this is db2 on AN as400.

Comment: @DanB. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684290/select-case-in-select-error-sql0115-comparison-operator-in-not-valid-in-quer) looks to be related then.

Comment: Thank you Richard, that helped a lot.