# SQL CASE WHEN IN

Tags: sql, db2, case

is it possible to use an IN operator in a CASE WHEN ?

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN DIGITS(A)||DIGITS(B) IN (SELECT DIGITS(C)||DIGITS(D) FROM TABLE_2)
    THEN x
    ELSE y 
    END AS MY_VAR
FROM TABLE_1
```

This gives me an error:

> Comparison operator IN not valid.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: it is IBM i series

Comment: Yes It is possible ! Could you share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: Note that `'12' || '34'` is equal to `'123' || '4'`. As desired?

Comment: try `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE DIGITS(TABLE_2.C) = DIGITS(TABLE_1.A) AND DIGITS(TABLE_2.D) = DIGITS(TABLE_1.B))`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/28684290/73226

Answer (score 0):

See [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=codes-listing-sql-messages#messages__SQL0115)

SQL0115

> Simple comparison operators other than equal and not equal cannot be
> used with a list of items. ANY, ALL, and SOME comparison operators
> must be followed by a fullselect, rather than an expression or a list
> of items. **Subqueries cannot be specified in a JOIN condition or in a
> CASE expression**.